# How to upload data in cloudsearch with boto

Tags: boto3

wanted to upload data in json format into AWS cloudsearch by using boto3

I read boto3 api documentation it is not helpling

client = boto3.client('cloudsearchdomain')
client.upload_documents(documents=data, contentType='application/json')

EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://cloudsearchdomain.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/2013-01-01/documents/batch?format=sdk"